# De-serializing Json with numeric properties in Unity

Tags: c#, database, curl, unity-game-engine, request

I am trying to get specific data from CURL but i get whole data Here is the code using

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class getRequest : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        string url = "https://blockchain.info/ticker";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));

    }
    IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
    {
        yield return www;

        // check for errors
        if (www.error == null)
        {            
            Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " +www.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
        }
    }
}
```

Geting OUTPUT like this

> WWW Ok!:  { "USD" : {"15m" : 1740.01, "last" : 1740.01, "buy" :
>   1740.01, "sell" : 1744.74, "symbol" : "$"}, "ISK" : {"15m" : 179479.11, "last" : 179479.11, "buy" : 179479.11, "sell" : 179967, "symbol" : "kr"}, "HKD" : {"15m" : 13551.08, "last" : 13551.08, "buy"
>   : 13551.08, "sell" : 13587.92, "symbol" : "$"}, "TWD" : {"15m" :
>   52292.17, "last" : 52292.17, "buy" : 52292.17, "sell" : 52434.32, "symbol" : "NT$"}, "CHF" : {"15m" : 1733.63, "last" : 1733.63, "buy" :
>   1733.63, "sell" : 1738.35, "symbol" : "CHF"}, "EUR" : {"15m" : 1584.76, "last" : 1584.76, "buy" : 1584.76, "sell" : 1589.07, "symbol" : "€"}, "DKK" : {"15m" : 11790.2, "last" : 11790.2, "buy" : 11790.2,
>   "sell" : 11822.25, "symbol" : "kr"}, "CLP" : {"15m" : 1161247.87,
>   "last" : 1161247.87, "buy" : 1161247.87, "sell" : 1164404.58, "symbol"
>   : "$"}, "CAD" : {"15m" : 2373.57, "last" : 2373.57, "buy" : 2373.57,
>   "sell" : 2380.02, "symbol" : "$"}, "INR" : {"15m" : 111442.86, "last"
>   : 111442.86, "buy" : 111442.86, "sell" : 111745.8, "symbol" : "₹"},
>   "CNY" : {"15m" : 11994.67, "last" : 11994.67, "buy" : 11994.67, "sell"
>   : 12027.28, "symbol" : "¥"}, "THB" : {"15m" : 60079.94, "last" :
>   60079.94, "buy" : 60079.94, "sell" : 60243.26, "symbol" : "฿"}, "AUD" : {"15m" : 2342.53, "last" : 2342.53, "buy" : 2342.53, "sell" :
>   2348.9, "symbol" : "$"}, "SGD" : {"15m" : 2434.82, "last" : 2434.82, "buy" : 2434.82, "sell" : 2441.44, "symbol" : "$"}, "KRW" : {"15m" :
>   1943939.17, "last" : 1943939.17, "buy" : 1943939.17, "sell" : 1949223.53, "symbol" : "₩"}, "JPY" : {"15m" : 197725.17, "last" : 197725.17, "buy" : 197725.17, "sell" : 198262.66, "symbol" : "¥"}, "PLN" : {"15m" : 6655.07, "last" : 6655.07, "buy" : 6655.07, "sell" :
>   6673.16, "symbol" : "zł"}, "GBP" : {"15m" : 1347.87, "last" : 1347.87, "buy" : 1347.87, "sell" : 1351.53, "symbol" : "£"}, "SEK" : {"15m" :
>   15356.67, "last" : 15356.67, "buy" : 15356.67, "sell" : 15398.41, "symbol" : "kr"}, "NZD" : {"15m" : 2522.84, "last" : 2522.84, "buy" :
>   2522.84, "sell" : 2529.69, "symbol" : "$"}, "BRL" : {"15m" : 5391.27, "last" : 5391.27, "buy" : 5391.27, "sell" : 5405.92, "symbol" : "R$"},
>   "RUB" : {"15m" : 98152.22, "last" : 98152.22, "buy" : 98152.22, "sell"
>   : 98419.04, "symbol" : "RUB"} }

**But I want output like this USD 1740.01 $**
Can any one please help me

Comment: What stops you from parsing the JSON result? If you want to receive only the value for USD you should have a look at the API documentation from blockchain.info , if they have one.

Comment: Is there any way to get only needed data from the JSON result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flagged as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity/36244111#36244111) but then re-opened after I realized that the Unity does not support the first value in the Json. Unity's `JsonUtility` cannot de-serialize the json data when it starts with an integer such as **15m**. It can de-serialize other data from that Json but you only want to de-serialize **15m** variable.

Download *SimpleJSON* from Unity's [wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON).

With `SimpleJSON`, this is how you get the USD's *15m* value:

```
var N = JSON.Parse(www.text);
string prize = N["USD"]["15m"].Value;
Debug.Log(prize);
```

Don't forget to import *SimpleJSON* with `using SimpleJSON;`

Comment: You are welcome. Will modify the answer from the "duplicated question"  to include jsons with numeric properties.